In this JavaScript code there any way I can log "hello" first before "goodbye"?
first(second);

function first(callback) {
    hello();
    callback();
}

function second(){
    goodbye(); 
}

function hello() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
    }, 3000);
}

function goodbye() {
  console.log('Goodbye');
  
}

I'm looking to find a way in Javascript where the second function runs only after the first function is fully completed without knowing how long it would take. I purposely put a timeout in Hello function to test this behavior. The duration of this timeout can range from a few seconds to a few minutes.

One way is to remove the setTimeout operation.  Or move console.log('Goodbye'); into the setTimeout operation, after the other log statement.  Or are you looking to wrap setTimeout in a Promise and await it, or something of that nature?  I guess it's not entirely clear to me what specific result you are trying to achieve from this otherwise academic example.

Please [edit] the question to explain any requirements or restrictions you have. Because the obvious answer is to rewrite the code to console.log('Hello'); console.log('Goodbye');, but there's likely more to it than this.

@David I'm looking to find a way in javascript where the second function runs only after the first function is fully completed without knowing how long it would take. I purposely put a timeout in Hello function to test this behavior. The duration of this timeout can range from a few seconds to a few minutes.

@LeviAJ: If the goal is to make setTimeout awaitable like a Promise, the linked duplicate can help with that.

@LeviAJ you must pass the callback to hello, and call it from there when it is "fully completed" (i.e. after logging "Hello" in your case). No other way to achieve that, the hello function must cooperate. Calling callback() immediately after hello() achieves nothing.

Instead of calling the callback function directly inside the first function, you can pass the the function as an argument into the hello function and then call it inside the setTimeout.
first(second);

function first(callback) {
   hello(callback);
}

function second(){
   goodbye(); 
}

function hello(callback) {
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Hello');
      callback();
   }, 3000);
}

function goodbye() {
   console.log('Goodbye');
}

You could also use a Promise and await. You could read more about it here
async function first(callback) {
  await hello();
  callback();
}

function second(){
  goodbye(); 
}

function hello() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
        resolve();
    }, 3000);
 });
}

function goodbye() {
   console.log('Goodbye');
}

first(second);


Please imagine that hello() and goodbye() functions are not editable. I want to execute all the contents inside the First() function first before the second() function in called. Is there any way to do that?

You could wrap the hello function like this helloPromise() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
hello();
setTimeout(resolve, 3000); // Resolve the promise after 3 seconds (assuming hello() takes 3 seconds to complete)
});
}
then you have to await the helloPromise in the first function like so: async function first(callback) {
await helloPromise();
callback();
}

@LeviAJ Unless hello allows you to pass a callback and/or returns a promise, you won't have any way to know when it's "done". There are hackish solutions though - if you could tell us what exactly that function is (show us the function or what libary it is), I might come up with a hack to achieve what you need (probably involving temporarily hooking another function).

You could use an async method and the then method to order the executions.
async function hello() {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Hello');
    }, 3000);
}

function first(callback) {
    hello().then(
       callback();
    );
    
}

Essentially this creates a promise object that and then waits for that promise to be resolved before executing the following code.

setTimeout doesn't return a Promise and isn't awaitable.  The linked duplicate on the question above shows how to wrap setTimeout in a Promise.  (Additionally, your code has a syntax error.)
